# docker-compose: can't access Django container from within Nuxt container

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, nuxt.js

Both my backend (localhost:8000) and frontend (locahost:5000) containers spin up and are accessible through the browser, but I can't access the backend container from the frontend container.

From within frontend:

```
/usr/src/nuxt-app # curl http://localhost:8000 -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying ::1:8000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Address not available
*   Trying ::1:8000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Address not available
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
```

My nuxt app (frontend) is using axios to call `http://localhost:8000/preview/api/qc/`. When the frontend starts up, I can see axios catching `errorError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000`. In the console it says `[HMR] connected` though.

If I make a change to `index.vue`, the frontend reloads *and then* in the console it displays:

`access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/preview/api/qc/' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. VM11:1 GET http://localhost:8000/preview/api/qc/ net::ERR_FAILED`

I have already setup `django-cors-headers` (included it in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` and `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True`).

In my `nuxt.config.js` I have set

```
axios: {
  headers : {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"],
  }
},
```

I'm stuck as to what is going wrong. I think it's likely my `docker-compose` or `Dockerfile`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
        - ./backend:/srv/app
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
        - db
    networks:
        - main

frontend:
    build:
        context: ./frontend
    volumes:
        - ./frontend:/usr/src/nuxt-app
        - /usr/src/nuxt-app/node_modules
    command: >
        sh -c "yarn build && yarn dev"
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
        - backend
    networks:
        - main

networks:
    main:
        driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:15.14.0-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

RUN npm install -g npm@latest

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 5000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=5000
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have 2 different errors.

The first one.

> My nuxt app (frontend) is using axios to call http://localhost:8000/preview/api/qc/. When the frontend starts up, I can see axios catching errorError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000. In the console it says [HMR] connected though.

This is SSR requests from nuxt to django. Nuxt app inside the container cannot connect to localhost:8000. But you can connect to django container via http://django_container:8000/api/qc/ where `django_container` is name of you django container.

In nuxt config you can set up different URLs for server and client side like this. So SSR requests go to docker django container directly and client side requests go to the localhost port.

`nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  // ...

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.browser ? 'http://localhost:8000' : 'http://django_container:8000'
  },

  // ...
}
```

The second one.

> access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/preview/api/qc/' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. VM11:1 GET http://localhost:8000/preview/api/qc/ net::ERR_FAILED

This is client side request from your browser to django. I think it's better to set `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` explicitly. Also you can allow `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS`. I can't guarantee it, but I hope it helps.

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:5000', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000']
```

Comment: I've managed to remove the second problems thanks to your help. For the first, I am sending a request to `http://backend:8000/preview/api/qc/`. On my log I can see `Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'backend:8000'. You may need to add 'backend' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`. So I've added `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['process']` but still get the same error.

Comment: @ron_g So try to add `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['backend']` to `settings.py`

Comment: Sorry it's called `process` in the code I have, and I copied/pasted. I meant that I have added `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['backend']` and it still gives me the same error. I'm trying something else today and will be back with answers.